# "Image too big" in draw.io stored on Google Drive using the diagrams.net plugin

Tags: google-drive, app.diagrams.net

I activated in my Google Drive the plugin "diagrams.net" and now I'm trying to draw shapes on top of an existing floorplan which happens to be a 2400x1600 pixel large image. Because of my use case I can't reduce the resolution of the image :(

Draw.io won't let me insert the image and shows "Image too big"

[image]

Unfortunately it doesn't tell my what the maximum size is. I even don't know how the size is measured: Is it in pixels, is it in MB? Does it depend on the file type I chose when creating the document?

Comment: Open configurations using Extras->Configuration... and past following json.
`{
  "maxImageSize": "9000",
  "maxImageBytes": "9000000"
}`
This would be allow you to upload larger images.

Answer (score 3):

Image too big is an error message when you try to load an image file that is larger than 1MB.
Simply replace `EditorUi.prototype.maxImageBytes=1E6` in app.min.js with 1E7.
Then it can read image files up to 10MB in size.

Use draw.io on localhost instead of in the cloud: http://localhost/draw-dev/src/main/webapp/index.html.
Just download the draw.io source code from the repo and replace the value setting in app.min.js.

See https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/issues/1887

Answer (score 0):

You can try to host images somewhere, copy image address and then link it in a diagram via URL (click "+" in the toolbar > Image)

This way file size should be smaller cause only image address is added, not the image itself.

Comment: I will give it a try for the next floor :) At the moment I ended up splitting the image in smaller parts. First of all I wanted to know, what is deemed "too big"